# issue using php checkdate function in if statement with $_POST

Tags: php, function, validation

I have a contact form

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" class="contact" autocomplete="on">
<input type="text" name="bot" class="hidden">
<table class="contact">
<tr>
    <th><label for="name">Name: </label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Yournamehere" 
    value="<?php echo $_POST['name'];?>" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><label for="date">Date: </label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" 
    value="<?php echo $_POST['date'];?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><label for="message">Comments: </label></th>
    <td>
        <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20"><?php echo $_POST['message'];?></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td> 
    <td>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

There are 6 fields total but I didn't include all the fields in the code because they are irrelevant. Basically I am trying to validate the date field with the checkdate function in PHP but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to check in an if statement if the $_POST['date'] is a valid date. I don't know if I can do it because of the way I have the textfield of the date? This is what I have for the php so far... it's not pretty lol

```
<?php
    $fields = array($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone'], 
    $_POST['occasion'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['location'], $_POST['message']);

    if (checkdate($month, $day, $year) == false) {
        $error[4] = "Please enter a valid date";
    }
?>
```

I don't know how to put put fields[4] somewhere to check what the user typed. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951177/how-to-use-checkdate-function-if-the-input-type-is-text-for-the-year) example and it helped somewhat but it seems different because I only have one field and not three... Help please!

Comment: You don't need to put the fields into an array `$_POST` is already an array with the fields you're creating a new array with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you're sure your users are going to submit the dates in the correct format (mm/dd/yyyy), you could do something like this:

```
<?php
    $date = explode("/", $_POST["date"]);
    if (checkdate((int)$date[0], (int)$date[1], (int)$date[2]) == false) {
        $error[4] = "Please enter a valid date";
    }
?>
```

Nonetheless, you should check whether the input is formatted correctly, look into regular expressions.

Comment: Oh yes sorry I will do that!! :)